# How do I fix a red opening tag

Tags: tags, h2

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhXYp.png)

All but two of my h2 tags are red and I can't figure out why. I've tried erasing them and re-writing it but I still get red and my words "fish" and "bird" are not formatted in h2. Also my picture of my bird is not displaying.

Comment: Your `img` tags aren't closed properly. Also, please don't post images of code - it's just text, so post it here directly, properly formatted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Here are quite a few reasons not to post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198). They're not searchable, not accessible to people using assistive technology such as screen readers, and can't be copy/pasted into a suitable IDE for a quick reproduction of the problem you're asking about.